# Managing HTTP requests and ViewModel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a CSHTML page and I'm having trouble finding the best way to structure my requests flow and maintaining a persistance of what is in the ViewModel with what is being displayed in the View.

I'm using an ASP.NET Web Service as API to connect the website to the database. This is how my Controller is populating the ViewModel before calling the View:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("company/sites")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CompanySites()
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Startup._tokenCookieName]);

    CompanyAccount user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyAccount>(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Startup._companyInfoCookieName]);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Company");
    }

    CompanySitesViewModel viewModel = new CompanySitesViewModel ();

    viewModel.LoggedInCompanyId = user.CompanyId;

    // Populate viewModel...

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class CompanySitesViewModel 
{
    public List<CompanyDTO> AdministratedCompanies { get; set; }

    public CompanySitesViewModel ()
    {
        AdministratedCompanies = new List<CompanyDTO>();
    }
}
```

And this is one of the places I access data from the ViewModel inside the View:

```
...
@if (Model.AdministratedCompanies.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdministratedCompanies.Count; i++)
        {
            <button class="list-group-item">
                <div>
                    <h6>@Model.AdministratedCompanies[i].CompanyName</h6>
                    @if (@Model.AdministratedCompanies[i].CompanyCnpj != null)
                    {
                        <span><small class="text-muted">@@Model.AdministratedCompanies[i].CompanyCnpj</small></span>
                    }
                </div>
            </button>
        }
    </div>
}
...
```

My problem starts when I want to manipulate the data displayed in this list. In instance, I want to remove one company from `AdministratedCompanies`. I'm currently doing a Ajax call directly to the API and, when receiving success, forcing a page refresh so the View gets updated without the deleted company.

This is the Ajax call:

```
function deleteCurrentSite() {
    if (currentCompanyIdToDelete != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Startup._apiConnectionString" + "sites/" + currentCompanyIdToDelete ,
            type: "DELETE",    
            success: function (e) {
                showAlert('Company deleted. Refreshing page...', true);
                // Has to reload page to refresh site list
                document.location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                showAlert('Error deleting company.', false);
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + '@Model.Token');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have background in React development, and it is incredibly easy to just change the `state` and have the view to be updated, and I seems very unoptimal to have to reload the whole page because of a change.

I have some ideas in mind to solve this:

1. Find the deleted company's div and delete it manually. Not optimal, even less when I want to add a company and have to create and append the component.
2. Have the Controller to store the ViewModel and have the Ajax call to send the ID I want to delete to the Controller, that then manages the API calls. But from what I found, if I use `RedirectToAction` or call the View again after the deletion, the page will still be refreshed (even though this seems a better approach as having Ajax to call the API).
3. Found some references to this library [BeginCollectionItem](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) to create a more dynamic binding between the View and ViewModel, but when I saw it was updated 7 years ago I didn't investigate further.

So **what is the best way of creating a dynamic binding between the View and ViewModel including CRUD operations and list redraw when changes occur?**

Comment: you can return JSON from the controller method, then the javascript will process the response data and update the page accordingly.  You've separated the view and data at that point... though the controller can update the data, and the javascript can update the view.

Comment: @pcalkins That would require me to manipulate the HTML appending and deleting divs, right? I always feel wrong doing that, I supposed there would be a better way with the CSHTML syntax and HTML helpers.

Comment: if you don't want to return JSON, you'd just leave those methods intact and have the javascript update a main DIV with another .cshtml file.  (Just a copy of the main one without the header/footer.)  It would bind to the same controller.  I've done this before and just pre-pended "jq_" to the name ex: "jq_pagename.cshtml"  So the javascript updates the main div with the jq_ page. Use partials so that updates to the partial updates both main and jq_ versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of some javascript (jQuery) for a simple get.  The handler passes the URL of the "jq_pagename.cshtml":

```
function DisplayError(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    errortext = error + jqXHR.responseText;

    $('#status').html('');
    $('#results').html(errortext);
}
function updateMainDiv(url) {
    $('#results').html('');
    data = "<img src='/images/waiting.gif'></img>";
    $('#status').html(data);
    $.get(url, function (data) {


        $("#results").html(data);
        $('#status').html('');
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        DisplayError(jqXHR, textStatus, error);
    });
}
```

For this technique I usually use partials for static view controls on the page... search, top-level nav, etc... and then for main content.  the main page includes those, the jq_ page does not.  The "results" div is only in the main page.  You are sending the GETs or POSTs to the jq_page via javascript and returning their HTML via javascript.  This way the exact same controller can be used to update the data and the view.  (You're just intercepting the returned HTML and putting it where you like.)  Here's an example of processing a form (onsubmit, or onchange select, etc..):

```
function ProcessFormPost(formID, destURL) {

    formresult = $('#' + formID).serialize();

    $('#super').html('');
    data = "<img src='/images/waiting.gif'></img>";
    $('#status-super').html(data);
    $.post(destURL, formresult, function (data) {


        $("#super").html(data);
        $('#status-super').html('');
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        DisplaySuperError(jqXHR, textStatus, error);


    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's quite interesting, didn't think of that before. Will test it tomorrow and will accept this if I that works.